# Parameter interups docker build

Tags: powershell, docker, dockerfile

I've created a dockerfile and now I want to build it, but I need to run a powershell command with a parameter inside. Running the command outside the docker build, then it works fine. Unfortionatly not when I run it inside the docker build.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/nanoserver COPY wrapperfiles /wrapperfiles

RUN powershell start-process -filepath "C:\wrapperfiles\wrapper.exe -s C:\wrapperfiles\tomcat-wrapper-default.conf"


EXPOSE 80

CMD ["powershell.exe", "-NoLogo", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"]
```

Now when I want to build it, then it comes with the following error:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  1.664GB  Step 1/5 : FROM microsoft/nanoserver  ---> e2c314f76df6 Step 2/5 : COPY wrapperfiles /wrapperfiles  ---> Using cache  ---> 6047da8320f0 Step 3/5 : RUN powershell start-process -filepath "C:\wrapperfiles\wrapper.exe -s C:\wrapperfiles\tomcat-wrapper-default.conf"  ---> Running in 0d6b47577b35 Start-Process : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 's'. At line:1 char:75
+ ... filepath C:\wrapperfiles\wrapper.exe -s C:\wrapper ...
+                                                                ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterB    indingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comm    ands.StartProcessCommand

The command 'cmd /S /C powershell start-process -filepath "C:\wrapperfiles\wrapper.exe -s C:\wrapperfiles\tomcat-wrapper-default.conf"' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

How can I get the -s parameter included in the filepath command?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get the -s parameter included in the filepath command?

`-s` cannot be part of a `filepath`, unless you have a file literally called `C:\wrapperfiles\wrapper.exe -s C:\wrapperfiles\tomcat-wrapper-default.conf`.

Probably you want to include `-s` and `C:\wrapperfiles\tomcat-wrapper-default.conf` as arguments, so try:

```
RUN powershell start-process -filepath "C:\wrapperfiles\wrapper.exe" -ArgumentList "-s","C:\wrapperfiles\tomcat-wrapper-default.conf"
```

Comment: `Step 3/5 : RUN powershell start-process -filepath "C:\wrapperfiles\wrapper.exe" -argumentlist "-s","C:\wrapperfiles\tomcat-wrapper-default.conf"
 ---> Running in b2348f6ce6b4
At line:1 char:91
+ C:\wrapperfiles\wrapper.exe -argumentlist -s,C:\wrapp ...
+                                                                 ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordEx
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument`

Also not giving the right solution, it triggers on the comma